# React suggestion showing in form of list

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use typeahaead through react-bootstrap-typeahead in my react app by using same example as mentioned in this question

[React: Suggestion is not showing in the drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717631/react-suggestion-is-not-showing-in-the-drop-down)

As per the answer mentioned in this question , I have imported CSS file as well. But still suggestions are shown in form of list when I click typeahead box.

### Code : Typeaheadsearch class using react-bootstrap-typeahead

```
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import { FormGroup, FormControl as Control } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Typeaheadsearch extends React.Component {
   state = {
    multiple: false,
  };

  render() {
    const {multiple} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          labelKey="name"
          multiple={multiple}
          options={[
            'Green',
            'Yellow',
            'Orange',
            'Red'
          ]}
          placeholder="Choose a name..."
        />
        <FormGroup>
          <Control
            checked={multiple}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({multiple: e.target.checked})}
            type="checkbox">
          </Control>
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Typeaheadsearch
```

I am calling this class from my App.js file

### Code : App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return <Typeaheadsearch />
  }
}
```

Output is as shown in image :

### Output

[image]

Can somebody please help.

I have search this particular css file and it is present in my project. Also, I tried by copying the contents of this file in my .css file file but still it is not working.

Also, I have inspected the UI and this type ahead CSS elements are present.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `react-bootstrap-typeahead` library is intended to work with [Bootstrap styles](https://getbootstrap.com/). It looks like you haven't included the CSS in your project yet.

Comment: Wjhat do you mean by not included CSS ? I am using a .cc file in my project for other styling of my component. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Sorry .cc is mistyped it is .css. Thanks

Comment: Thanks you were right , after importing bootstrap it worked.